# What company means in Liferay

Tags: liferay

There are organizations, users, roles and groups in Liferay. But there are many methods in liferay API that returns company or need company id as argument. E.g. `UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(long companyId, String emailAddress)` or `com.liferay.portal.model.User` `getCompanyId()`.

For what purpose the `company` is provided in Liferay? Why I have to provide company id to find user by email address?

[Documentation](http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/Company.html) does not say too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - you can have more than one portal instance in the same server (in the same database) and you need "companyId" to avoid db data conflicts between those instances. A single instance itself is a full portal with users,groups,roles and everything else. Having "companyId" you can save, for example, two users with same emailAddress for different instances.